# c# new mail from outlook with attachment

Tags: c#, wpf, email, outlook

This has been asked before in one way or another, but i need some clarity on an issue I am having.

essentially, my client wants his app (wpf, written in VS2010) to be able to create new messages in his outlook (not send them, but just popup with the new mail message with certain fields filled in - he will type up the rest of the body and then send)

So to date I have just been going the route of using the mailto:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(string.Concat(@"mailto:" , toAddress , "?subject=" , subject));
```

easy peasy.

Now he wants attachments to be included. Doing some reasearch I see that there once was an &Attach tag I could add, but it doesn't work for me. further research revealed that its been killed off since office 2007 (I have 2013 installed on my box, client has all different types) so I cant use this method.

Further reasearch suggests that i go the COM automation route. there are nice tuts online like [this one on MSDN](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/CSAutomateOutlook-a3b7bdc9)

seems simple enough but I get stuck at this point

> Step1. Create a Console application and reference the Outlook Primary Interop Assembly (PIA). To reference the Outlook PIA, right-click the project file and click the "Add Reference..." button. In the Add Reference dialog, navigate to the .NET tab, find Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook 12.0.0.0 and click OK.

Now I have a bunch of different ones (v11 - v15)
[image: office interop files]
I guess because of different versions of office I have had.
Now my question is

1. Which version should I pick
2. What happens when I publish (clickonce) and deploy to my client given that their machines all have different versions of office.

Will the highest version accommodate them all? 
Can I pick one to suite them all

(note: It has to happen through outlook so i cant use the normal .net mail method - that would have been great if i could)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My recommendation is not to use PIAs, use NetOffice instead, as it provides a very nice abstraction and will work with any Office version (https://netoffice.codeplex.com/). Will also work nice with Clickonce distribution.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up going for a self rolled Late Binding Com solution myself (which it seems NetOffice uses under the hood anyways). Thanks for the suggestion tho, Ill use this next project for sure